# Transactions on a new token get Error: Provided owner is not allowed

Tags: token, error, liquiditypool

I am looking at transactions for newly listed live new pairs tokens on solana. On solscan.io, I have noticed some early transactions for a few tokens (within the first few seconds of the liquidity pool being added) can get the `error: Provided owner is not allowed`.

Example of one of the transactions with the error (expand program log):
https://solscan.io/tx/2JvVkeHALL4m6PV6dgLyCecfGWhbw3Ju53Mm1q5EZqPtUed3zkK24RjWujUVM1EK5t3fB1dQ8xpCzA6opudLNM8g

What does this error mean? To me it suggests that the token has a whitelist active for the first few seconds, so only specific wallets can buy, but does it mean something else?